# Scripting/AHK - Mimicking double left-click selection of a single word

Tags: scripting, mouse, autohotkey

**The goal of my script:**

While reading a .txt file in Notepad I want to lookup a word in a dictionary without using the mouse.

**My idea of the functionality:**

1. With the keyboard I move the text-cursor to the word I want to look up.
2. When positioned right, perform same functionality as a double left-click. So it selects the word only.
3. Copy the selected word and use that to open an URL like: `Run dictionary.com/?="SELECTED_TEXT"`.

**So the Question is..**

How do I mimic such a double-click. Or perhaps other options to easily select a single word using only the keyboard.

**Background**

I'm using an Asus Transformer with Windows 8.1. I'm reading books on it in .txt format only. I don't like using the touch pad nor add a mouse to it. That's why I have converted most actions to AutoHotkey scripts. And would like to add this functionality as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class Notepad

~LButton Up::
  If (A_ThisHotkey == A_PriorHotkey && A_TimeSincePriorHotkey <= 300)
  {
  MouseGetPos,,,, Controlname
    If Controlname = Edit1
   {
    ClipSaved := ClipboardAll
    clipboard =
    Send, ^c
    ClipWait, 2
    Run http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/%clipboard%
    Sleep, 300
    Clipboard := ClipSaved
   }
 }
 return

#IfWinActive
```